# Convert a column of text URLs into active hyperlinks in Shiny

Tags: r, hyperlink, datatables, shiny, dt

I am creating a user interface for a pathway enrichment program. The results are shown in a table as shown below.

[image]

Below is a snippet showing that I am using DT::renderDataTable and DT::datatable to output the table in a tab. spia_out() is just a reactive function that runs the pathway enrichment and produces a dataframe.

```
spia_out <- reactive({
    ...get results in a dataframe...
  })

output$spiaout <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(spia_out(), extensions = ..., options = ...)
  })
```

Everything works fine, the pathway enrichment table is generated & printed in the corresponding UI element. My only problem is how to convert the last column (KEGGLINK) of URLs into active hyperlinks? So that people can just click on them instead of copy & pasting.

Apologies in advance for the screenshot's size. I hope you can see the last column KEGGLINK has URLs but they are not active.

Comment: See answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909826/r-shiny-open-the-urls-from-rendertable-in-a-new-tab

Comment: @KenYeoh, that answer is not entirely applicable as here the question relates to DT:renderDataTable, not shiny:renderTable and if he does what is suggested there it won't work because of DT will escape the HTML by default.

Comment: @jrdnmdhl Exactly! It doesn't work because I am using DT::renderDataTable and not shiny::renderDataTable

Comment: Alternatively, it's also possible to keep the original dataframe intact and tell dataTable how to render a column. See section 4.4 Column Rendering in the [DT docs](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html).

Comment: In the link, there is no example that would do hyperlinks. Can you add the actual code.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Modify the last column so that the KEGGLINK is changed into a proper HTML link that looks like: `<a href='url'>link text</a>`.
2. Pass DT the `escape = FALSE` argument so that it doesn't escape the HTML code.

The DT web page has an example of this in section 2.9:
https://rstudio.github.io/DT/

A simple way to do #1 would be something like:

```
mydata$url <- paste0("<a href='",mydata$url,"'>",mydata$url,"</a>")
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! However, this opens in the same tab. I could right click and select open in new tab but is there a way to open the link in a new tab, by default?

Comment: Got it! `mydata$url <- paste0("<a href='",mydata$url,"' target='_blank'>",mydata$url,"</a>")`

Comment: It's section 2.10 now instead of 2.9.

Comment: Is there a way to factor this still by the name of the links, i.e. the html_text() as factors but keep the column as links?